# Flex: List displaying wrong until scrolled

Tags: apache-flex, list, flex3

I have a List, that is not showing any items until you scroll, then the items show up. Does anyone know how to fix this? I tried calling **list.invalidateDisplayList();** and **list.invalidateList();** But with no luck.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT: Here is some code:

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        [Bindable]
        private var _xmlList:XMLList = new XMLList();


        override public function set data(value:Object):void
        {
            this.setStyle('borderColor','#cc6666');
            var xmllist:XMLList = XML(value).children();
            _xmlList = xmllist;
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:List id="list" width="100%" height="100%" labelField="@user" dataProvider="{_xmlList}" itemClick="onItemClick(event)"/>
```

I found that if I add **creationComplete="{list.dataProvider = _xmlList }"** It solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also trying adding

```
super.data = value
```

Answer (score 2):

You might try calling:

```
list.validateNow();
```

This causes an inline, synchronous control refresh.  The `invalidateDisplayList()` call just tells the control that *the next time it's drawn*, it should re-compute the display list.  It doesn't force the refresh immediately.